# Why am I getting a cartesian project with this join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to create a query for a report. I have a table of `licenses` and a table of `users`, and I have `license_assignments` as a many to many table to assign license seats to users:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE license_assignments ( `uid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, `lid` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL, `delta` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`lid`, `delta`), KEY `uid` (`uid`));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO license_assignments VALUES (1, 2, 1), (1,2,2), (1,2,3), (NULL, 2, 4), (NULL, 2, 5), (NULL, 2, 6);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * FROM license_assignments;
+------+-----+-------+
| uid  | lid | delta |
+------+-----+-------+
| NULL |   2 |     4 |
| NULL |   2 |     5 |
| NULL |   2 |     6 |
|    1 |   2 |     1 |
|    1 |   2 |     2 |
|    1 |   2 |     3 |
+------+-----+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The report I want to create must show me the total number of license seats belong to a particular license ...

```
mysql> select COUNT(lid) FROM license_assignments all_licenses WHERE lid = 2;
+------------+
| COUNT(lid) |
+------------+
|          6 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

... and how many of those seats remain unassigned (no related user record):

```
mysql> select COUNT(lid) FROM license_assignments unassigned_licenses WHERE lid = 2 AND uid IS NULL;
+------------+
| COUNT(lid) |
+------------+
|          3 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

However when I put those two queries together with a natural join, I get the cartesian product (3 x 6 = 18):

```
mysql> select COUNT(all_licenses.lid) as all_licenses_count, COUNT(unassigned.lid) as unassigned_count FROM license_assignments unassigned, license_assignments all_licenses WHERE unassigned.lid = 2 AND unassigned.uid IS NULL AND all_licenses.lid = 2;
+--------------------+------------------+
| all_licenses_count | unassigned_count |
+--------------------+------------------+
|                 18 |               18 |
+--------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thinking I just needed to add a `GROUP BY`, I did so, but it didn't help:

```
mysql> select COUNT(all_licenses.lid) as all_licenses_count, COUNT(unassigned.lid) as unassigned_count FROM license_assignments unassigned, license_assignments all_licenses WHERE unassigned.lid = 2 AND unassigned.uid IS NULL AND all_licenses.lid = 2 GROUP BY all_licenses.lid, unassigned.lid;
+--------------------+------------------+
| all_licenses_count | unassigned_count |
+--------------------+------------------+
|                 18 |               18 |
+--------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I supposed that natural joins were tripping me up, so I tried inner joins:

```
mysql> select COUNT(all_licenses.lid) as all_licenses_count, COUNT(unassigned.lid) as unassigned_count FROM license_assignments unassigned INNER JOIN license_assignments all_licenses ON all_licenses.lid = unassigned.lid WHERE unassigned.uid IS NULL;
+--------------------+------------------+
| all_licenses_count | unassigned_count |
+--------------------+------------------+
|                 18 |               18 |
+--------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I failing to understand? I expect to perform a query that gives me this result:

```
mysql> select COUNT( ... ;
+--------------------+------------------+
| all_licenses_count | unassigned_count |
+--------------------+------------------+
|                 6 |               3 |
+--------------------+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But my set theory is apparently rusty. What do I need to do?

BTW:

```
mysql> select version();
+-------------------+
| version()         |
+-------------------+
| 5.5.31-1~dotdeb.0 |
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a cartesian product because one set is six rows with lid=2, and the other set has three rows with lid=2. Each row in a set is being matched with EVERY row in the other set.

The problem with the JOIN here is that you need to guarantee that a row from set one will match at most one row from set two... you need a join predicate on a UNIQUE key.

If you absolutely needed to use a JOIN to get this resultset, then this would work:

```
 SELECT COUNT(a.lid) AS all_licenses_count
      , COUNT(u.lid) AS unassigned_count
   FROM license_assignments a
   LEFT
   JOIN license_assignments u
     ON u.lid = a.lid
    AND u.delta = a.delta
    AND u.uid IS NULL
  WHERE a.lid = 2
```

Note that the JOIN predicate is matching on both `lid` AND `delta` (which is defined as UNIQUE KEY in the table definition.) So we are guaranteed that a row from set one (a) will match at most one rows from set two (u).

As other answers have noted, using a JOIN like this is not the most efficient way to get that result.

There are several ways to return an equivalent result, but the most efficient approach is usually along the lines of doing a single pass through the table to pick out "all" rows, and then use an expression that performs a conditional test to determine whether the row should be included in another COUNT or SUM aggregate.

I'd write something like this:

```
 SELECT SUM(1)             AS all_licenses_count
      , SUM(a.uid IS NULL) AS unassigned_count
   FROM license_assignments a
  WHERE a.lid = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The query is much simpler than you think :)

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) all_licenses_count,
  COUNT(*) - COUNT(uid) unassigned_count
FROM license_assignments
WHERE lid = 2
```

The `COUNT(*)` counts rows while `COUNT(uid)` counts rows that have `uid` not null.

Output:

```
| ALL_LICENSES_COUNT | UNASSIGNED_COUNT |
|--------------------|------------------|
|                  6 |                3 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b6dae/1).

Comment: Definitley best approach here.  Count the values not the rows.  No need for join here at all.

Comment: Actually this is backwards -- `COUNT(uid)` would be assigned seats, not unassigned seats. I can't immediately think of how to change it to correct it.

Comment: Actually I guess `(COUNT(*) - COUNT(uid)) unassigned_count` works.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mike Brant mentioned above, you don't need to JOIN for just `COUNT()`ing. Not sure why you need join, Anyway if you want, **You are missing JOIN CONDITION**. Here is example.

```
SELECT
  unassigned.lid, unassigned.delta
FROM
  license_assignments unassigned JOIN
  license_assignments all_licenses 
  ON unassigned.lid = all_licenses.lid AND unassigned.delta = all_licenses.delta
WHERE
  unassigned.lid = 2 
  AND unassigned.uid IS NULL 
  AND all_licenses.lid = 2
+-----+-------+
| lid | delta |
+-----+-------+
|   2 |     4 |
|   2 |     5 |
|   2 |     6 |
+-----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

IF you check below queries, you can figure out what's the problem.

```
SELECT uid, lid, delta 
FROM license_assignments all_licenses
WHERE lid = 2;
+------+-----+-------+
| uid  | lid | delta |
+------+-----+-------+
|    1 |   2 |     1 |
|    1 |   2 |     2 |
|    1 |   2 |     3 |
| NULL |   2 |     4 |
| NULL |   2 |     5 |
| NULL |   2 |     6 |
+------+-----+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT uid, lid, delta 
FROM license_assignments all_licenses
WHERE lid = 2 AND uid IS NULL;
+------+-----+-------+
| uid  | lid | delta |
+------+-----+-------+
| NULL |   2 |     4 |
| NULL |   2 |     5 |
| NULL |   2 |     6 |
+------+-----+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Part of me also wants to understand why a cartesian product is happening, and if I can prevent it by join syntax alone. Can you enlighten me?